# Reorder the Basic page list in views .How?

Tags: views

I have created views to display basic pages in blocks.I what to reorder the list according to me .How to do?Plz help......

Comment: Add sort fields to view...

Comment: Do you want to **sort basic pages** based on **created date** (ascending or descending)? Or your trying to sort based on your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 7 you use **VIEWS SORT CRITERIA**

- If you want to sort based of **Content: Post date** OR **Content: Updated date** just use these fields in **VIEWS SORT CRITERIA**.
- If you want to sort based on your requirement then, just add one more extra field to basic page like weight.

  [image: enter code here]
- Edit your VIEW and just add this field in the **Views SORT CRITERIA** and sort is as per
  your requirement.

  [image]

Comment: It really helped me....solved my problem.thanks a lot...